# Jquery table row add stoping

Tags: javascript, jquery

View link keeps adding rows to table upon each additional click. I need to stop ıt.
I have 2 objects ın a JavaScript array, whıch ıs passed to prıntfeed functıon by GetVıewData.
When I clıck on each vıew lınk It adds 2 rows, whıch ıs fıne. After clıckıng agaın ıt adds 2 more, and so on. How could I stop thıs functıonalıty?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".anch").click(function(e) {           
    GetViewData(trID);
});

function GetViewData(pid) {
var data = [ {"FeedID":"10", "TranslateText": "test"}, {"FeedID":"11", "TranslateText": "test"}];           

$.each(data, function (i, item) {
         printFeed(div, item,TableID );
 });

function printFeed(div,item,tableName) {        
        var iTableName = "#" + tableName;
        var newRow = $("<tr><td>test</td></tr>");
        $(iTableName).append(newRow);

    }  

<a class="anch">view</a>  
<div id="ajaxDiv-1">
    <table id="Table2">
        <tr><td>test</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>  
<a class="anch">view</a> 
<div id="ajaxDiv-1">
    <table id="Table3">
        <tr><td>test</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want the user to be able to click the button only once?

If so you can use the jQuery .one function. http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: I have changed the script like below, still excutes GetViewData(trID) function 
when i click on link "view" which is selected by ".anch" 

    $(".para1").hide('slow');
    $(".anch").one("click", function() {
    $(".para1").hide();
    $(this).parent().children(".para1").slideToggle(500);                     
    $('#resultTable tr').unbind('click').click(function(){
    var trID = $(this).attr('id')
                              
       
    GetViewData(trID); 
    div").children().attr("id") 
                
    });
        
    });

Answer (score 0):

Variety of ways incluiding using `one()` as previously posted. This has limitiation that handler will work once and only once.

You can have a conditional statement to see if you need to run the code within the handler or not.

```
var ctr=0;

$(selector).click(function(){
   if( ctr < 3){
      /* run code*/
   }
   ctr++;
});
```

Or you can remove the handler using `unbind()` or `off()`

```
if( myFavoriteColor === 'Green'){
   $(selector).unbind('click')
}
```

or

```
$(selector).click(function(){
   if( ctr < 3){
      /* run code*/
   }else{
       $(this).unbind('click')
   }
   ctr++;
});
```